# Adding objects into an HTML canvas with ja

Tags: javascript, object, canvas, dynamic

I'm extremely new to javascript, and I'm trying to make a very simple canvas game. I want to add multiple enemies, but I want them to appear randomly, not all be hardcoded in. How would I create new objects/enemies every 5 seconds? Sorry for the probably very simple question, I have to learn this somehow, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create enemies array and push to it:

```
var enemies = [];

setInterval(function(){

    enemies.push({
        x: Math.ceil(Math.random() * canvasWidth),
        y: Math.ceil(Math.random() * canvasHeight)
    });

}, 5000);
```

Comment: You can also take a look at this simple Asteroids game implemented using HTML5 canvas - http://jiri.hybek.cz/sandbox/asteroids.html

Comment: Ok it's going to take a while to put in, but I've never heard of the push() method. That seems like the solution, though, so big thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you can add a "set interval" function to JavaScript. This will allow you to run some code every five seconds.

```
 setInterval(function(){
  // your code to be executed every 5 seconds goes here.;
},5000);
```

You can also have random objects or enemies by using a random number generator. For example:

```
setInterval(function(){

//Math.random() returns a random number between 0 and 1.
 intRandomNumber = Math.random() * 10;


//Math.round() returns the nearest whole number
intRandomNumber = Math.round(intRandomNumber);


if (intRandomNumber == 1){
//create some monster
}
else if (intRandomNumber == 2){
//create some object
}

    },5000);
```

Comment: I know how to de the interval and random numbers, my main problem is the dynamic object thing. I want to make a new enemy every few seconds, which requires me making a new object every time.